# Show buildings and their numbers in free drive

Tags: android, skmaps

When the app enters a "free drive", buildings and their numbers disappear from the map. How to prevent this?
Tried

```
SKMapSettings.setHouseNumbersShown(true);
```

but it doesn't help.

Code:

```
SKNavigationSettings configuration = new SKNavigationSettings();
configuration.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.REAL);
configuration.setDistanceUnit(SKMaps.SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER_METERS);

SKNavigationManager navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
navigationManager.setMapView(mapView);
navigationManager.setNavigationListener(...);
navigationManager.startNavigation(configuration);

SKMapSettings mapSettings = mapView.getMapSettings();
mapSettings.setHouseNumbersShown(true);
mapSettings.setMapDisplayMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_2D);
```

Skobbler SDK v2.5.1 for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible right now due to some past design decisions - once you enter "navigation" the house numbers & buildings disappear.

Right now there is nothing you can do, in the future we'll consider making this behaviour configurable.

Comment: Thanks, got it. What I tried to achieve is to get info from callbacks (currentSpeed, speedLimit) all the time, even if the user is not Navigating or not in Free Drive.
But seems it is impossible without Free Drive. So I tried to use Free Drive all the time (while not Navigating). But this makes map less detailed which is not appropriate.
It would be good to have currentSpeed and speedLimit updates without impact on the map.